# If I marry a convert without my parents' permission, but with my brother's permission, is it valid?

Tags: nikah

I am a 25-year old Muslim woman living in the UK with my parents and siblings, and I have been in love with a non-Muslim man for 3 years. We agree this will not lead anywhere, both out families would not agree.

We thought about him converting, so I asked my mum if I can get married to a convert, but she said no. I don’t want to go against my parents decision, plus the Nikah wouldn't be valid without my parents' consent.

I explained the situation to my brother, that I don’t want to get married to anyone else. He said if he converts, I have permission to marry him.

If I go ahead with this Nikah when my parents do not agree and my older brother gives me his permission, will the Nikah be valid?
I have 2 older brothers that will be there with me.

I asked the first part of my question here:  [Can a girl tell her parents that she doesn’t want to get married at all?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47767/can-a-girl-tell-her-parents-that-she-doesn-t-want-to-get-married-at-all)

Comment: @III-AK-III I've added a link to this [Who can be wali and in what order](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/who-can-be-wali-and-in-what-order) to my answer as without such an explanation it wouldn't be a good duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

The Shafi'i fiqh book *The Reliance of the Traveller* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliance_of_the_Traveller)) makes two relevant points here:

1. After your father's permission, next in line is your paternal grandfather (father's father) and so on up, then brothers, with first precedence going to the oldest brother.  (*The Reliance* slightly differs from [Who can be wali, and in what order?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39553/17163) in that it doesn't mention sons.)

   > (m3.7) None of the above may marry her to someone when a family member higher on the list exists.

   Your mother's permission doesn't enter into the validity of the marriage (although there are matters of undutifulness to your mother ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=362863))).
2. A woman has the right to marry a suitable match:

   > (m3.9) Whenever a free woman asks to marry a suitor who is a suitable match ..., the guardian must marry her to him

   with some exceptions, the relevant one here is:

   > (m4.1) Suitability concerns lineage, **religiousness**, profession, and being free of defects that permit annulling the marriage contract ...

Basically, the father has an Islamic right (even duty) to refuse to marry his daughter to a man of poor religiousness, which may apply here.

However, an individual case would need a scholar and a fatwa.